# How to just download Oracle ODBC Driver in 2020?

Tags: oracle, odbc

I could download only ODBC before,but I had found the oracle website changed and only found `ODAC` and it contaions `ODBC Driver`,it have to download another softwares,like oracle sql*plus,developer tools for visual studio etc.

[image]

the link : https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdeploy-downloads.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installation instructions are at  https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/releasenote-odbc-ic.html

In summary, use [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html).  Install either the "Basic" or "Basic Light" package, and then the "ODBC" package.

Comment: I would rather suggest the "ODBC Package" which is also  available when you scroll down in the download page. The "Basic" does not include the ODBC driver, i.e. you would have to use the ancient and deprecated Microsoft ODBC driver `Microsoft ODBC for Oracle`

Comment: That is indeed the package my answer says to use.  But you still need Basic or Basic Light as well, since the ODBC's package library depends on it.

Comment: Yes, I missed that due to missing quotes around *ODBC package* But second sentence is still valid.

Comment: I added quotes; I agree they help when scanning the text.  And thanks for the extra info about the problems if the ODBC package isn't used.

Answer (score -1):

You can download ODBC Driver https://www.devart.com/odbc/oracle/
This is a pretty good connectivity solution